# About the measure theory

Tags: real-analysis

In the marden's analysis book, a set A in the euclidean space is defined to have measure zero if for arbitrary epsilon, there exist a covering of A by countable closed rectangles such that the sum of the volumes of them is less than epsilon.

My question is, can the closed rectangles be replaced by any volume for the set to have measure zero? The problem in the book says yes. I see the one way is clear but i don't know how to prove the other direction: if the set can be covered by the countable sets( not necessarily closed rectangles!) whose sum of the volumes is less than the arbitrary epsilon, then the set has measure zero.

Comment: How do you define volume?

Comment: A bounded set in the euclidean space is said to have a volume if its characteristic function is integrable, and its volume is the riemann integral of char. ftn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, and the proof uses two basic properties of measure. First it uses the fact that if $A \subseteq B$ then $m(A) \leq m(B)$. Second it uses the fact that $m \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right ) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A_n)$. (Here all sets I mention are measurable.) Using both of these with any given cover of your measurable set by countably many measurable sets will do the job. But note that these properties are theorems, not definitions. By contrast, $m(A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(R_n)$ where $R_n$ are rectangles and $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty R_n$ is taken to be a *definition* in one of the common constructions of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't see how to construct the countable set of rectangles that cover the measurable set A from the arbitrary countable cover of A. I didn't learn the concept of measure. In class i was taught only what the concept of measure zero is ( as stated in the question)

Comment: @Mathcho OK. Then let $A$ have a countable cover by measurable sets $A_n$ of total measure less than $\varepsilon/2$. For each of them, let $R_{m,n}$ be a cover of $A_n$ by rectangles of total measure no more than $m(A_n)+\varepsilon/2^n$. Then there are countably many $R_{m,n}$ and they are a cover of $A$ by rectangles of total measure at most $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Okay that is neat. Thank you so much